# Setting BackColor of Row based on data - DataBoundItem of the Last row of DataGridView is Null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm having the following issue with Windows Forms: I need load some data in a `DataGridView`. The issue is that the object corresponding to each row has a `Color` property specifying the back color for that row.

So I've tried the following code:

```
SourceContactStatus.DataSource = _contactStatusAppService.LoadGridData();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridContactStatus.Rows)
{
    ContactStatusGridViewModel vm = row.DataBoundItem as ContactStatusGridViewModel;

    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(vm.Color);
}
```

Where `SourceContactStatus` is a data source from where the `DataGridView` gets the data and where `_contactStatusAppService.LoadGriData()` returns a `IList<ContactStatusViewModel>` which is built by using a repository.

Now,this doesn't work because when the `foreach` loop starts, the `GridContactStatus.Rows` property has zero elements. I believe this is because the data binding isn't complete, because later on the rows appear there.

The problem is that I'm trying to set the backcolor before the data bind is done.

I've tried putting that same `foreach` loop inside the `GridContactStatus.DataBindingComplete` event handler, but then I get one exception because something is null.

**EDIT:** The code I've used when trying to wire up the code using the `GridContactStatus.DataBindingComplete` event handler was this one:

```
GridContactStatus.DataBindingComplete += (sender, args) =>
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridContactStatus.Rows)
    {
        ContactStatusGridViewModel vm = row.DataBoundItem as ContactStatusGridViewModel;

        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(vm.Color);
    }
};
```

Now I've debugged this piece of code and found out that one of the `rows.DataBoundItem` is null. To test it out I added 3 items, all the three are found correctly. But the `GridContactStatus.Rows` has 4 elements and the last one has `DataBoundItem = null`.

**(1) Why the `DataBoundItem` of the last row is `null`?**

**(2) How can I solve this issue and correctly set the backcolor of each row based on that `Color` property?**

Comment: *"but then I get one exception because something is null."* can you provide more details about what is null? perhaps we can help you track it down. Include a code example as a edit that uses the DataBindingComplete event and include details about which specific object is null.

Comment: Thanks for the aid @ScottChamberlain. Indeed I thought it was just plain wrong to do it in that way that I didn't even investigated more. I tried debuging with that extra code and found out that it is one of the data bound item that was null. I've added the code and details in one edit. Now, I'm wondering: is the best way to set this background color to wire up the code in the DataBindingComplete event handler? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I think the 4th row with nothing in it is the "New Row", try setting [`AllowNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.allownew(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks it solve the problem!

Comment: Post a full answer to help other people having the same problem

Comment: **(1)** When `AllowUserToAddRows` property of `DataGridView` is set to true, there is a new row at the end of the `Row`s collection which its `DataBoundItem` is `null`. When you want to perform an operation in a loop on actual data-bound rows, usually you need to exclude that row. The main sign of the row is its `IsNewRow` property is `true`. So you can exclude it from the loop.

Comment: **(2)** A more suitable way to apply formatting to cells, is using [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`. For example you can apply back color using `e.CellStyle.BackColor`. Pay attention that the event will also raise for rows and columns header, so the value of `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex` may be `-1` which you should neglect them when you want to perform dynamic formatting on cells.